# Pass php variables to js without drupal behaviour

Tags: 8, javascript

I stand on the following tricky situation:

I have a node with geofield coordinates attached. I am constructing an array of points. Something like:

```
Array
(
[86] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 39.1641410477
                [lon] => -2.633972168
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 41.0420738489
                [lon] => -2.633972168
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 41.0420738489
                [lon] => 1.2524414063
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 39.1641410477
                [lon] => 1.2524414063
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 39.1641410477
                [lon] => -2.633972168
            )
    )

[85] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 39.1641410477
                [lon] => -2.633972168
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 41.0420738489
                [lon] => -2.633972168
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 41.0420738489
                [lon] => 1.2524414063
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 39.1641410477
                [lon] => 1.2524414063
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 39.1641410477
                [lon] => -2.633972168
            )
    )
)
```

I want to pass this to my-googlemaps.js in order to be used by google's init map
Google map is defined as:

```
my-map:
  header: true
js:
  js/my-googlemaps.js: { }
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key&callback=initMap: {type: external, attributes: {defer: true,async: true}}
dependencies:
  - core/drupal
  - core/drupalSettings

my-googlemaps.js:
  console.log(Drupal.settings);
  function initMap() {}
```

This way I get Drupal.settings undefined, which makes sense I guess.
On the other hanve if I place initMap into a behavior It can not be seen as a callback as defined in googleapis.com before.

Has anyone stumbled with this before? Any idea how to attack the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can follow [document](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets).

> Attaching configurable JavaScript
>
> In some cases, you may want to add JavaScript to a page that depends
>   on some computed PHP information.
>
> In this case, create a JavaScript file, define and attach a library
>   just like before, but also attach JavaScript settings and have that
>   JavaScript file read those settings, via drupalSettings (the successor
>   to Drupal 7's Drupal.settings). However, to make drupalSettings
>   available to our JavaScript file, we have to do the same work as we
>   had to do to make jQuery available: we have to declare a dependency on
>   it.
>
> So that then becomes:

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

> and

```
$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/cuddly-slider';
$build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['fluffiness']['cuddlySlider']['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Where 'bar' is some calculated value.

> Then cuddly-slider.js will be able to access
>   drupalSettings.fluffiness.cuddlySlider.foo (and it will === 'bar').

In your case. You need use hook_preprocess_node() to add array geofield.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_node($vars) {
  // You nedd process to get $geofield
  $vars['#attached']['drupalSettings']['geoField'] = $geofield
}
```

and file js/my-googlemaps.js you need code.

```
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.yourbehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
       var geoField = drupalSettings.geoField.
      // You can init map here.
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Comment: but this solution is buggy and cache the value, as an example 
I've added in preprocess on node
`$vars['#attached']['drupalSettings']['my_rand'] = rand(2,9999999);`

and in my js 

`(function ($, drupalSettings) {
    Drupal.behaviors.stripe = {
        attach: function (context) {
            console.log(drupalSettings.my_rand);

        }
    };
})(jQuery, drupalSettings);`
always return the first generated item and cache till until I rebuild the cache it doesn't chage.

Comment: @zhilevan You need to add cache tag node. Following [topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256286/how-to-set-cache-meta-data-on-drupalsettings)

Comment: can you add it in your solution for the question sample?